# Web Workers creation inside Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-worker

I saw that's possible to do ajax requests inside a web worker, but I want to do the ajax call via jQuery (outside worker, of course), and after this, pass the result of the callback to the worker.
I made some tests and this works, but I want to know if there's something wrong with it (memory leaks, incompatibility, instability):

```
  $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'GET', 
            url : 'http://192.168.0.2/json.php',
            data: requestDataObj,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function(jsonResult)
        {
            var jSonWorker = new Worker('http://localhost/webmail/responsive/js/workers.js');
            jSonWorker.postMessage(jsonResult);
            jSonWorker.onmessage = function(event)
            {
                alert(event.data)
            }
         });
```

As you can see, I pass the jsonResult to the worker, where I do something with it and post a message back to the main thread. Anything wrong with this?

Comment: You have code that works. You don't have a problem to solve. You're just asking for opinions on its quality. This is off-topic for Stackoverflow. It might be better suited to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok that's nice. i didn't knew about this.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that you're assuming any browser has support for `window.Worker`, which is not the case.

In case blocking the application is feasible — say the computation you're expecting the worker to do is light — you could *paste* the entire code of the worker inside the ajax callback [1].

Thus

```
...success(function (res) {
    if (window.Worker) {
        var worker = new Worker(...);
        worker.onmessage = function (e) { /* ... */ };
        worker.postMessage(res);
    }
    else {
        // Write here the same code the worker
        // is supposed to execute "on" res.
    }
});
```

Course you will lose the performance improvement you gained with two threads.

---

[1] As done [here](https://github.com/afshinm/50k/blob/master/index.html#L78-L117) by @afshinm.